# Can't reject suggested edit after selecting then deselecting "custom" reason

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't reject suggested edit after selecting then deselecting “custom” reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115665/cant-reject-suggested-edit-after-selecting-then-deselecting-custom-reason)

When I'm rejecting an edit, I'm asked to provide a reason. There are some predefined choices, and a "custom" choice.

When I select the "custom" choice, the dialog's submit button is disabled until I write enough characters in the freeform text field. However, if I change my mind and now select one of the predefined choices, the dialog's submit button is *still* disabled.

It should be re-enabled without my having to first write some dummy text in the freeform text field.

Comment: Oh, hang on. This is a duplicate of a _very poorly-titled_ existing post.

Comment: The same bug exists in the dialog, but for rejecting tags.  Same deal.  You have to click over to another radio button, then back to the custom reason radio button, then back again in order to get out of custom reason hell.