# Remove disabled state after custom offtopic cv reason

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

Steps to reproduce:

1. click close on a question
2. click offtopic because...
3. click other (without typing any text)
4. click sscce reason
5. Repeat 3-4 a few times.

Issue:

The submit button is still disabled

Expected:

The submit is enabled again.

Tested in FF and Chrome

Proof: http://postimg.org/image/5u71sp1e5/

Comment: Chrome on Windows 7 - can't repro.

Comment: Hmm, no repro on Chrome here (Win7). Version 28.0.1500.72 m

Comment: Can you test it on main? BTW it looks like something it works and sometimes it doesn't. Toggle it a couple of times. Also try other reasons.

Comment: I did. Tried with Opera, IE 10, FF and Chrome.

Comment: I did test it on main. Can't seem to repro. What versions are you using?

Comment: Versie 28.0.1500.72 m

Comment: Let me see whether I can make a screeny

Comment: I just ran into this earlier today (Chrome latest on Windows). If you type some custom text, then change your mind and select another option, you can't click "Submit" until deleting the custom text.

Comment: [Can't reject suggested edit after selecting then deselecting “custom” reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115665) and [Can't reject suggested edit after selecting then deselecting "custom" reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122462)

Comment: BINGO: Reproduced. But that took me a hell of a lot of attempts. http://i.imgur.com/ebO87rO.png

Comment: I actually encountered this a few days ago, however I thought it wasn't important enough since it will happily fix itself if you select another reason again

Comment: @Bart sometimes I get it the first time sometimes after a couple of tries.